# Is it ok to affect boolean while testing?

Tags: java, java-5

**EDIT:** Totally rewrote the question since the original is unclear.

Is it a bad practice to do the folowing in cases you need to keep the *someTestMethod* return value to perform further tests?:

```
    boolean foo;
    if(someCondition || (foo=someTestMethod()) || someOtherConditions){
        //do stuff depending on foo value
    }
```

Because I am testing a boolean and affecting it at the same time, which is what caused me to wonder if everything was right. I am writing the test this way because *someTestMethod* cost a lot of time, and I don't want it to be called if the first test passes.

I have to add that I have simplified a lot, please don't reply about how the test could be rewritten, I only want to know if you can safely write *if(foo=someTest())*, which leads to test a variable and affecting it at the same time.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better site for this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for code to be reviewed, this should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: the outer if of your example is unnecessary. Anyway if ((b1= somemethod()) is a very bad practice.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated to essentially achieve the same thing as `if (p(x, y)) {...} else if(p(y,33)) {...} else if (p(x,33)) {...}`. (the else if part is only evaluated if necessary)

Comment: As stated in my edit this is not a code review request but a theoretical question about the language.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing technically wrong with what you've done. It will work with any Java compiler.

However the following is equivalent and, to me, clearer.

```
 if(p1(x,y) {
     println("I only ran p1");
 } else if (p2(x,33)) {
     println("I only ran p2");
 } else if(p3(y,33)) {
     println("Ran all three");
 }
```

But there's an implied part of this that's not in your example. Presumably you want to do something else with the OR'd result. It's better then to have a method:

```
if(combinedConditions(x,y) {
     doSomething();
}

boolean combinedConditions(int x, int y) {
    if (p1(x,y)) {
        println("I only ran p1");
        return true;
    }
    if (p2(x,33)) {
        println("I ran p1 and p2");
        return true;
    }
    println("I ran all three");
    return p3(y,33);
}
```

More generally, "debug" printlns are bad news.